# Data transfer from a big table to other new tables in Sybase

Tags: sql, sap-ase, data-transfer

I have a requirement wherein I need to break down a large table having 50M records into two tables based on one condition on one column.
I do not want to use "insert into table1 select * from table2 where condition = true " statement.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the easiest method?  Performance concerns? Other reasons?  Does the table have to physically separated, or could you accomplish it using views instead?

Comment: Use `select * into <new table>`. This will not use the log and fastest way to insert after BCP. However, you will have to create constraints/indexes/triggers if any on the new table manually. They do not get copied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 views to select the data you want to send to your 2 tables.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use the easiest method, here are a couple of options using `bcp` and views.

If you only need to create one new table:

1. Create a view of your table, with the true condition statement.
2. BCP the data out of that view, and into a new table.
3. Delete true condition records from original table.

If you need to create two new tables:

1. Create view of table with true condition
2. Create view of table with false condition
3. BCP the data out of both views, and into new tables